# Any action is redirected to the root

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP for the first time and I have a trouble with requests.

I have for example this simple controller:

```
class TestController extends AppController
{
    public function index() {   

    }

    public function edit() {    

    }

    public function view() {

    }
}
```

Index is rendering right but when I call **/test/edit** or **/test/view** I am redirected (302) to the root of my webpage. Views for each action are created.

It's the same for any other controller in my app.

I cannot figure out why. Do you have any ideas, suggestion what should I check?

Comment: Can you check if you have defined your route ?

Comment: Paste your route file also.

Comment: I have routes like this, eg.:
$routes->connect('/test/edit/*', ['controller' => 'Test', 'action' => 'edit']);

Answer (score 0):

Thi was the problem `$this->Auth->allow(['edit']);` now it is working.